# How do I determine the instantiated name of a class when I create it

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, properties

I have a class with a few members and properties and when I create it how can I know what the instantiated name is at the time of creation?

I have a class PDInt and so I'll instantiate it as a member and then will wrap that member in a property.  Here is the class and followed by the property:

```
    public class PDInt : PDBase
{
    #region Members

    int m_Value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( m_Value != value )
            {

            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public PDInt()
    {
        this.Init();
    }

    public PDInt( int Value )
    {
        this.Init();
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public PDInt( int Value, string ControlName )
    {
        this.Init();

        this.Value       = Value;
        this.ControlName = ControlName;
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        this.Value = 0;
    }

    public void Map( int Value, string ControlName )
    {
        this.Value       = Value;
        this.ControlName = ControlName;
        this.Validate    = true;
    }

    public void Map( int Value, string ControlName, bool Validate )
    {
        this.Value       = Value;
        this.ControlName = ControlName;
        this.Validate    = Validate;
    }
}
```

Here is member and then property usage

```
        PDInt m_PrescriptionID;
    public PDInt PrescriptionID
    {
        get
        {
            if ( m_PrescriptionID == null )
            {
                m_PrescriptionID = new PDInt();
            }

            return m_PrescriptionID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( m_PrescriptionID == null )
            {
                m_PrescriptionID = new PDInt();
            }
        }
    }
```

It would be very helpful to me to be able to determine programatically what the actual instantiated name is so I can put it in a string inside of the class to be referred to later.

I am using reflection throughout my app and I just can't seem to figure out how to get at the name when the class is instantiated.

Thanks.

Comment: instantiated name == variable name ???

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you would like to know in a class what is the instance name that is used from somewhere else when the class is instantiated?

If that is so - you can't.  c# don't allow that.

EDIT:

Why do you need that?  Maybe you have a problem that can be solved some other way?

Comment: Thank you for asking.  I want to know the name of the class when it is instantiated so I can use it to populate a Name property in the class.  That way I don't have to use reflection later if I need to know the name of the class.

Comment: That's not the name of the class, it's the name of the INSTANCE. You'll have to set it by hand.  For example, in a constructor this.Foo = new Bar("Foo");

Comment: Yes, I want to know what the instance of a class is, pro grammatically during creation.